# Assign matrix columns as elements of a list

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a messy loop in some old code.

Let's say I have a list `list1`, a matrix `mat1`, and a vector of indices `ind1`, something like:

```
list1 <- list(2:4, 1:3, 11:19, 36:42)
list1
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 3 4
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42

matrix1 <- matrix(1:16, nrow=4, ncol=4)
matrix1
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    5    9   13
## [2,]    2    6   10   14
## [3,]    3    7   11   15
## [4,]    4    8   12   16

indices1 <- 1:2
```

Is there a clean way of extracting columns of `matrix1` of indices `indices1`, that is, `matrix1[,indices1]` and assigning each **column vector** to a corresponding **list element** in `list1`, that is, `list1[indices1]`

... all with the desired output

```
list1
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 5 6 7 8 
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
```

This would definitely be possible with a loop or apply-type function, but my hope is for something more efficient.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1[indices1] <- data.frame(matrix1[,indices1])
```

I'm not sure whether it's efficient enough. It seems to achive what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I'm away from my machine right now, but that looks simple & promising.

Comment: Tried this solution in my code and it worked just fine - however, it didn't end up adding anything in performance in context (was only looping for 3-4 iterations at a time). Lesson learned: repeating a simple process a few times can be more efficient than a complex process once. But thanks again!